# NTLM Authorization using Apache NameBased VirtualHosts over SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ntlm, namevirtualhost

I have a development environment that is fronted via an Apache server. This apache server requires SSL and Centrify-enabled NTLM authentication/authorization with the AD backend, using group access to view the webpages. There will be multiple projects using this environment, so I want to set up Virtual Hosting, which will allow each project to modify their own virtual host with any specific apache modules. The web files will live in /var/www/project1 ; /var/www/project2 ; etc..

I already have the DNS configured properly to point *.domain to the apache server, as well as a wildcard SSL certificate that had the altDNSName field set with *.domain.

The problem is the NTLM authentication piece:

If I point my browser to https://hostname.fqdn/project1/index.html, the NTLM authorization processes exactly as I want. I believe this runs off my default virtual host.

If I instead point my browser to https://project1.domain/index.html, the Apache error logs complain that "User failed NTLM authentication for /index.html. Error: Logon failure.

```
<VirtualHost ipaddress:443>
    Servername "hostname.fqdn"
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /path/to/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /path/to/cert.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ipaddress:443>
    ServerName "project1.domain"
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/project1"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /path/to/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /path/to/cert.key
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    SSLRequireSSL

    AllowOverride None

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/project1">
    AuthType CENTRIFYDC

    EnableBasicAuth     false
    EnableKerberosAuth  false
    EnableNtlmAuth      true

    Require group       required_ad_group
</Directory>
```

I have attempted this with both IE and Firefox, making sure *.domain was in my Local Intranet zone for IE and that the *network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris* and *network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris* settings are properly set in Firefox.

I have narrowed it down to the NTLM problem, because if I remove the Centrify directives, the Name-Based Virtual Host works as I would expect. I have tried placing the Directory tag within each Virtual Host, I have also tried using a Location tag, but I have not been able to make any headway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by making 2 solidly separate VirtualHosts that work as expected, and then work back to a hybrid variety by step changes.

I suspect your 2 VirtualHosts resolve to something like this;

```
<VirtualHost ipaddress:443>
    Servername "hostname.fqdn"
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /path/to/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /path/to/cert.key

<Directory "/var/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    SSLRequireSSL

    AllowOverride None

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/project1">
    AuthType CENTRIFYDC

    EnableBasicAuth     false
    EnableKerberosAuth  false
    EnableNtlmAuth      true

    Require group       required_ad_group
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ipaddress:443>
    ServerName "project1.domain"
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/project1"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /path/to/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /path/to/cert.key



<Directory "/var/www/project1">
    AuthType CENTRIFYDC

    EnableBasicAuth     false
    EnableKerberosAuth  false
    EnableNtlmAuth      true

    Require group       required_ad_group
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

So I would test something like that, and then move them out of each other sub-directories, and see what directives are conflicting

Comment: Thank you. I restructured the Virtual Hosts and Directories as you suggested, but I'm getting the same result. I started using Firebug for Firefox and can confirm that Apache is infact prompting for NTLM authentication from both Virtual Hosts, and the browser is responding with an NTLM token each time. Apache/Centrify just isn't processing the token when it comes from the project1.domain Virtual Host

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation, it wasn't a problem with the Apache configuration. It seems as though the browser was passing NTLM and Apache was receiving it, but Centrify isn't properly validating it. Now I need to figure out where the breakdown is here, but that's another thread.